# Evaluating BlocksInFlightPerAddress from Spark UI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, shuffle

Sometimes in a Spark job, we face OOM issues like the ones below:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 42748346368, max: 42749067264)
```

```
OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (​used: 7633633280, max: 7635730432)
```

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 71 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 62.3 GB of 62 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead
```

These posts suggest tweaking the Spark memory configurations so that Spark doesn't run out of direct memory while reading shuffled data:

- https://splice.atlassian.net/browse/SPLICE-2349?oldIssueView=true
- [spark shuffle memory error: failed to allocate direct memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808693/spark-shuffle-memory-error-failed-to-allocate-direct-memory)

Turns out these are the shuffle configs to tune to prevent this from happening:

- spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight
- spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight
- spark.reducer.maxBlocksInFlightPerAddress
- spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem

The downside of bad parameter tuning is increasing job latencies due to slow shuffles. In an effort to find optimal values for these, I want to find out what are the current metrics for these. (I know the default values for these from spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

But, **Is there a way to know or evaluate these metrics from the Spark UI or logs? i.e. What is the inflight size/reqs/blocks being utilised during the shuffles? Or at least, which metrics are indicators to approximately estimate this?**

Comment: Since there are no responses to this question, have you had any luck through other mediums to find these metrics?

Comment: great question, any luck with this?